# Java Map can't get boolean

Tags: java, dictionary, boolean

I have a Map like this:

```
Map<String, Boolean> settings = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

if I create a new boolean like this:

```
boolean bool = settings.get("something");
```

with or without (boolean) Gradle says:

```
Cannot cast java.lang.Object to java.lang.boolean
```

(Well, this Object is a boolean)
If I try to do parseBoolean(String) Compiler works fine, but if I execute, I get:

```
Cannot cast java.lang.Boolean to java.lang.String
```

So, what should I do, i know that the first is right and works for other people.

Edit: A little fault, Gradle says:

```
Object cannot be converted to boolean
```

Which means pretty much the same.

Comment: boolean is a primitive type use Boolean instead.

Comment: You get this error if your `Map` is declared without type information. Are you sure it has type `Map<String, Boolean>` and not `Map`?

Comment: @Jens Why autoboxing/unboxing work here ?

Comment: `Boolean bool = (Boolean) settings.get("something");` perhaps ?

Answer (score 1):

The method `get` will return `Boolean` (Object) which is wrapper over `boolean`(primitive). Hence you may need to apply cast.

Comment: Thanks, really dumb fault of me, for other reading this, just do (Boolean) settings.get("sth")

Comment: Before JDK 5 his code would not compile at all as generic declaration would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Keppil: Corrected :)

Comment: Why would autoboxing/unboxing not work automatically? There shouldn't be any need for explicit casting here, so OP's question must be missing vital information.

Answer (score -3):

Depending on your situation, maybe you don't need to store a boolean at all?
Would it be enough to use a HashSet and add Strings only if their value is 'true'?

Then you could write:

```
boolean bool = settings.contains("something");
```

Comment: Could you explain why this answer is voted down? It may not work in this case, but that doesn't make it a bad answer...

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I expect that the down-voter thought that your answer did not answer the question.  The OP wants to know >>why<< he got the error.

Comment: Thanks, but the OP asked "So, what should I do", so I did try to answered that ...